# Pyserial read loop requires multiple inputs to register

Tags: python, while-loop, arduino, microcontroller, pyserial

I am new to Python and programming in general.
I am in the process of making a remote control for Spotify using an Arduino and python.
Whenever a button is pressed on the Arduino, a single character is sent via serial.  There is a python script listening for this character and based on what the character is it executes a command.  The problem that I am having is that the `spotify.playpause()` works every time its respective button is pressed, but all the other commands require multiple button presses.  I am sure it is not an issue with the Arduino because I have confirmed via multiple serial monitors that the character is being sent correctly, so I believe that it is an issue with the Python loop.

EDIT:  Just adding more information, it seems that different combinations of `serial.read()` or `serial.readline` on the python side and `Serial.print` or `Serial.println` on the Arduino side have no effect on the issue

TL;DR  The loop doesn't fully execute, what's wrong with it.

Here is the code:

```
import serial
from pytify import Spotify
spotify = Spotify()
connected = False

ser = serial.Serial("COM3", 57600)

while not connected:
    serin = ser.read()
    connected = True

while True:
    if ser.read() == '0':
         spotify.playpause()
    elif ser.read() == '1':
        spotify.volumeUp()
    elif ser.read() == '2':
        spotify.volumeDown()
    elif ser.read() == '3':
        spotify.previous()
    elif ser.read() == '4':
        spotify.next()
    else :
        pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you keep calling ser.read for each if/elif case, so you are discarding the value each time your comparison fails.  You need to call ser.read only once, then compare that result using a local var, like this:

```
c = ser.read()

if c == '0':
   spotify.playpause()
elif c == '1':
   spotify.volumeUp()
...
```